# Found a swap file by the name

Tags: git, github, git-merge, dvcs, swapfile

When I try to merge my branch with a remote branch:

```
git merge feature/remote_branch
```

I got this message:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp"
          owned by: xxxxxx   dated: Mon Nov 12 23:17:40 2012
         file name: ~xxxxxx/Desktop/My-ios-App/.git/MERGE_MSG
          modified: YES
         user name: xxxxxx   host name: unknown-b8-8d-12-22-27-72.lan
        process ID: 1639
While opening file ".git/MERGE_MSG"
             dated: Tue Nov 13 14:06:48 2012
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.
    If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
    different instances of the same file when making changes.
    Quit, or continue with caution.

(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r .git/MERGE_MSG"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Looks like you have an open `git commit` or `git merge` going on, and an editor is still open editing the commit message.

Two choices:

1. Find the session and finish it (preferable).
2. Delete the `.swp` file (if you're sure the other git session has gone away).

Clarification from comments:

- The *session* is the editing session.
- You can see what `.swp` is being used by entering the command `:sw` within the editing session, but generally it's a hidden file in the same directory as the file you are using, with a `.swp` file suffix (i.e. `~/myfile.txt` would be `~/.myfile.txt.swp`).

Comment: How to find this .swp file?

Comment: How to find "the session" - what does it mean?

Comment: By finishing it, what exactly option should I choose? Edit or Recover it?@trojanfoe

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to finish the session or delete the file?

Comment: see my answer below for details on how to remove the .swp file

Comment: @OlehLiskovych It's in the git message or just search your git directory for a .swp file.

Comment: rm -rf  ~.MERGE_MSG.swp   should work @LeticiaEsperon @ OlehLiskovych

Comment: How do I "Find the session"? If I'm running `:sw` in my current editing session, that's not the same as the previous editing session, which in my case is probably from a server-closed ssh session that I no longer have access to.

Comment: I don't have an ongoing commit nor merge, I can't figure out how to remove this effing file.

Comment: It's not very useful to use the expressions "find the session" or "finish the session" unless you define them.

Comment: @user65526 See the first point in the *Clarification from comments* bit.

Comment: But what does "find the editing session mean"?

Comment: @user65526 The editing session in `vi` (or `vim`).  The OP is editing the merge commit message.

Comment: But how do you "find the editing session"?

Comment: @user65526 It'll be in one of your terminal windows I assume so Alt-Tab until it shows up.  If you are having problems then ask a start a new question.

Answer (score 41):

Accepted answer fails to mention how to delete the .swp file.

> Hit "D" when the prompt comes up and it will remove it.

In my case, after I hit D it left the latest saved version intact and deleted the **.swp** which got created because I exited VIM incorrectly

Comment: thank you - to whomever is crafting this in the bash program - there should be a comment along the lines of: "If you'd like to keep your changes, and delete the old changes - press D"

Comment: or just hit git clean -f

Answer (score 9):

### Feb, 2022 Update:

Remove `.MERGE_MSG.swp` to avoid `E325: ATTENTION`.

```
rm .MERGE_MSG.swp
```

Normally `.example.swp` file is not important.

In addition, normally `.example.swp` file is made in the same directory of the original file. Then, you cannot list `.example.swp` files with `ls` on terminal. You need to use `ll` or `ls -a` commands to list `.example.swp` files on terminal.

Answer (score 6):

.MERGE_MSG.swp is open in your git, you just need to delete this .swp file. In my case I used following command and it worked fine.

```
rm .MERGE_MSG.swp
```

Comment: To add to this: The folder may be hidden so you first have to run: cd .git

Comment: rm: .MERGE_MSG.swp: No such file or directory

Comment: To run the command, if your .MERGE_MSG.swp is hidden then must need go to the directory where the file is exist. @ScottyBlades

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this error when trying to pull the changes into a branch which is not created from the upstream branch from which I'm trying to pull.

Eg - This creates a new branch matching `night-version` of upstream

```
git checkout upstream/night-version -b testnightversion
```

This creates a branch `testmaster` in local which matches the `master` branch of upstream.

```
git checkout upstream/master -b testmaster
```

Now if I try to pull the changes of `night-version` into `testmaster` branch leads to this error.

```
git pull upstream night-version //while I'm in `master` cloned branch
```

I managed to solve this by navigating to proper branch and pull the changes.

```
git checkout testnightversion
git pull upstream night-version // works fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

More info...
Some times .swp files might be holded by vm that was running in backgroung.
You may see permission denied message when try to delete the files.

[image: Check and kill process vm]

Comment: That image is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when you try to update/rebase the feature/child branch with the master branch. It can be simply solved using the below git commands,
First of all, Just type E and hit the Enter button, then write the below commands one by one:

```
Press i (i for insert)
write your merge message
Press esc (escape)
write:wq (write & quit)
then press enter button
```