# What exactly are .Podfile.swp and Podfile.save

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I was trying to commit my Xcode project files using Sourcetree when these two files where shown. What exactly are these files?

[image: files]

Answer (score 3):

They're temporary files from a git merge that might still be in-progress.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361874/78496

Comment: Can we delete this file?